# REST Jersey exception AbstractJAXBProvider

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have this resource

```
@Path("customer")
public class Customers
```

inside it, I have this function:

```
@Path("signin/{mobileNumber}/{simNumber}/{password}")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public CustomerImpl signgin(@PathParam("mobileNumber") String mobileNumber,
            @PathParam("simNumber") String simNumber,
            @PathParam("password") String password) {
        // return "dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd";
        return CustomerWraper.instance.getOne(1);
    }
```

when I call that function I got exception,

I am using `customerWraper` :

```
public enum CustomerWraper {
    instance;
    private Map<Integer, CustomerImpl> customers = new HashMap<Integer, CustomerImpl>();

    public Map<Integer, CustomerImpl> getData() {
        return customers;
    }

    private CustomerWraper() {
        CustomerImpl c = (CustomerImpl)CustomerImpl.getCustomer(1);
        this.customers.put(1, c);
    }

    public CustomerImpl getOne(int ID) {
        CustomerImpl customer = getData().get(ID);
        if (customer == null) {
            //customer = (CustomerImpl) CustomerImpl.getCustomer(ID);
            customer = new CustomerImpl("0999440921", "123", "123");
        }
        return customer;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

The customerImpl class is like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class CustomerImpl extends com.syriatel.eattel.user.User implements
        Customer {
```

The User class Is abstract.

The exception is: (It is long, look at the end of it)

```
May 20, 2013 1:49:12 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 23 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl.getCustomer()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl.getCustomer()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getArea()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getArea()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.City is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.City
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.City com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getCity()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.City does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.City
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.City com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getCity()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getRegion()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getRegion()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood.getFood()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood.getFood()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteRestaurant does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteRestaurant
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteRestaurants()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getAddress()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getAddress()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getRestaurant()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getRestaurant()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
java.sql.Timestamp does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.sql.Timestamp
        at public java.sql.Timestamp com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getEndDate()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getOrder()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getOrder()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl

    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 23 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl.getCustomer()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl.getCustomer()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getArea()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Area com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getArea()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.City is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.City
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.City com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getCity()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.City does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.City
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.City com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getCity()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getRegion()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.Region com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl.getRegion()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.AddressImpl
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddressImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getAddresses()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood.getFood()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.food.RestaurantFood com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood.getFood()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteFood
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteRestaurant does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.FavoriteRestaurant
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getFavoriteRestaurants()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getAddress()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.location.CustomerAddress com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getAddress()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.FoodOrder
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getFoods()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getRestaurant()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.user.Restaurant com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getRestaurant()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
java.sql.Timestamp does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.sql.Timestamp
        at public java.sql.Timestamp com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getEndDate()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getOrder()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl
com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.Order com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus.getOrder()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus
        at public com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderStatus com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl.getStatus()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.order.OrderImpl
        at public java.util.List com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl.getOrders()
        at com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:151)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the interesting line for you from your stack trace;

```
com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
```

Your stack trace clearly showing a lot more classes as compare to what  you have posted. Please review your code again. Somewhere the "Customer" interface is referenced directly or is referenced in a way that is causing Jersey to try to initiate it directly.

I would suggest getting rid of Interface altogether if you can, just for now, only to make sure this is the real culprit.

Comment: I removed all the classes except customer, customerImpl, user , now I have this exception `A message body writer for Java class com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl, and Java type interface com.syriatel.eattel.user.Customer, and MIME media type text/html was not found`

Comment: You still have something referring to the Customer interface somewhere. That is not going to be easy to find. The message for CustomerImpl is confusing for me. this happens when you don't have any xml mappings in the implementing class, but I can see you have that on  CustomerImpl  @XmlRootElement(name = "customer")  Maybe the fact that CustomerImpl implements Customer has something to do with it. Also IMHO restarts really do help, though I still have no idea how :)

Comment: I have no idea why you are getting this. `MIME media type text/html was not found`

Comment: I removed the Customer Interface, now I have just customerImpl and user (which is abstract), I got this exception `SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl, and Java type class com.syriatel.eattel.user.CustomerImpl, and MIME media type text/html was not found
May 20, 2013 4:11:10 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
`

Comment: Looking at the error message; there seems to be something causing jersey to return a response in text/html or perhaps something is sending a request in text/html. Double check your REST Client if it is requesting correct mime type, i.e., text/xml. I still don't think it will be easy for you to find out what's wrong. I would suggest start from scratch and add your complexities bit by bit, very slowly. Only that way you may be able to dig out what is messing up with your application. I am still confused by the `text/html was not found` message, this does not look right.

Comment: after removing every thing, i discover the wrong, you wont believe that, The JDBC driver is not compatible with sql, I download the older vergion and NOW IT IS WORKING BUDDY

Comment: LOL, surprise surprise... I was expecting something like that. Thanks for sharing with us. the error message was bothering me since beginning, it never looked right.